# Antonym of test run

Tags: single-word-requests

I have developed an algorithm that aims to produce some scientific results. These calculcations use a lot of computing time, so most runs use a much faster, stripped-down version of the algorithm.
At some point, real runs are necessary for which a lot of time will be commited.

What would you call these runs that are not test runs? Live runs maybe?

Comment: "Crash" is what I usually encounter.  But "live run" fits, more or less.

Comment: Since they're probably *all* "tests", perhaps you should just differentiate them as *stripped-down* (or *preliminary*) tests and ***full tests***.

Comment: Could you clarify? Which one are you calling the test run? The longer one or the shorter one?

Comment: I'm calling the shorter runs test, i.e. those where I don't expect useful results.

Answer (score 4):

In many environments a run that actually produces results is a **production run**.  **Working run**, or some variant of *Live run*, *real run* or *actual run* might also work.

Answer (score 1):

If the Final run is called Test,
my scanner labels something similar a preview. Or perhaps,

***Sweep***

> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweep
>   .3.  to move or pass quickly, forcefully, or smoothly